# VBA macro for connexion with ODBC for retrieve data in excel

Tags: vba, excel, odbc

I try to retrieve some SQL data with excel. It works fine with a usual query (data->other sources->microsoft query.)

I try to create a maccro for that, and i'm actually block with the connexion/identification.

a piece of my macro below :

```
Sub Test()

'Declare a Connection object
Dim cnDB As New ADODB.Connection

'Declare a Recordset Object
Dim rsRecords As New ADODB.Recordset
cnDB.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DSN=ServiceNow;User ID=test;Password=testtest;"
```

The debug say the cnDB.Open is not good : "execution erro '-2147418113 (8000ffff)' Catastrophic failure". I've already tried many way to fix that but I didn't find..
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I created ODBC DSN for SQL Server 2012 Express
Then I recorded a macro in MS EXCEL 2010 (Use Developer tab).
There was no problem.

My connection information is as shown here:

"ODBC;DSN=sqlSrvr2012;UID=mysorian;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;WSID=HODENTEKWIN7;DATABASE=Northwind;"

Looks like you are getting data from MS ACCESS. It should be no different, perhaps you MS Access database needs correct authentication information. The complete code is in my G+

Answer (score 0):

What is the database you are looking to retrieve data from?

This may help - http://www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: It from ServiceNow http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Using_the_ODBC_Driver_in_Excel_2010  a SAAS ERP. Usualy it use SQL server 2008